# What are the step by step actions needed to upgrade a holochain rust back end from 0.0.1 to 0.0.2?

Tags: holochain, holochain-rust

I started by reviewing the Api notes and comparing them:
https://developer.holochain.org/api/

### What I have done so far:

#### Preparation:

Downloaded and installed 0.0.2, and then updated the bash_profile following this link:
https://developer.holochain.org/start.html

#### JSON PARSE/Stringify update

Updated all of the tests to remove any JSON.parse and JSON.stringify calls as they are no longer needed, for example replacing this:

`JSON.stringify({})`

with this:

`{}`

#### Derive function update

Updated all derive functions in zome definition files ( lib.rs ) to include Debug and DefaultJSON, like this:

`#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, DefaultJson)]`

#### Json String update

Did a global find and replace for all zome files on the JsonString
    changing the serde_json call to look like this :

replacing

`-> serde_json::Value`

with

`->   JsonString`

so it looks like this:

`fn handle_create_action(action: Action, user_address: HashString) ->
    JsonString { ...`

#### Current errors

I am running to these errors:

`error: cannot find derive macro DefaultJson in this scope`

`error[E0412]: cannot find type JsonString in this scope`

how can we import these into the lib.rs files?

## Update

This is by no means a comprehensive answer, but here are some of the additional steps I have found with help.

You will also need to edit the cargo.toml file of each zome, the dependencies part, to look like this:

```
serde = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
hdk = { git = "https://github.com/holochain/holochain-rust", branch = "master" }
holochain_core_types = { git = "https://github.com/holochain/holochain-rust", branch = "master" }
holochain_core_types_derive = { git = "https://github.com/holochain/holochain-rust", branch = "master" }
holochain_wasm_utils = { git = "https://github.com/holochain/holochain-rust", branch = "master" }
```

This was found with the specification app which is already up to date with the release that happened last night, at this page:
https://github.com/holochain/dev-camp-tests-rust/blob/master/zomes/people/code/Cargo.toml

Each zome needed this as a replacement for everything above the `#derive` function:

```
#![feature(try_from)]
#[macro_use]
    extern crate hdk;
    extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
    extern crate serde_derive;
#[macro_use]
    extern crate serde_json;
    extern crate holochain_core_types;
#[macro_use]
    extern crate holochain_core_types_derive;

use hdk::{
    holochain_core_types::{
    dna::zome::entry_types::Sharing,
    hash::HashString,
    json::JsonString,
    entry::Entry,
    entry::entry_type::EntryType,
    error::HolochainError,
    cas::content::Address,
    },
};
```

This resolved the initial errors on compile, and showed me the next layer of changes needed via terminal feedback when I ran `hc test` to compile, build and test the app... this is what I am seeing now..

### Error 1

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 parameter but 2 parameters were supplied
  --> src/lib.rs:56:11
   |
56 |     match hdk::commit_entry("metric", json!(metric)) {
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 parameter
```

### Error 2

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:60:24
   |
60 |                 return json!({"link error": link_result.err().unwrap()});
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `holochain_core_types::json::JsonString`, found enum `serde_json::Value`
```

I will attempt to resolve this one by replacing the serde_json calls in the zome code with JsonString...

### Error 3

```
error[E0609]: no field `links` on type `hdk::holochain_wasm_utils::api_serialization::get_links::GetLinksResult`
  --> src/lib.rs:82:18
   |
82 |                 .links
   |                  ^^^^^ unknown field
```

### Error 4

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_json` found for type `hdk::error::ZomeApiError` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:97:32
   |
97 |             "error": hdk_error.to_json()
   |                                ^^^^^^^
```

## Update 2

@connorturlands answer got me through most of those errors, and now there appears to be just one more.

```
^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default

error[E0063]: missing fields `active`, `date_time`, `description` and 12 other fields in initializer of `Metric`
  --> src/lib.rs:48:68
   |
48 |     let metric_entry = Entry::new(EntryType::App("metric".into()), Metric{
   |                                                                    ^^^^^^ missing `active`, `date_time`, `description` and 12 other fields

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0063`.
error: Could not compile `metrics`.
```

Which is in response to this zome definition:

```
fn handle_create_metric(metric: Metric, user_address: HashString) -> JsonString {

    let metric_entry = Entry::new(EntryType::App("metric".into()), Metric{
        // => Here is where the error triggers... it wants me to define 'title, time, etc' but as a core function, I don't see the point, those will be inputted.. not sure how to address this
    });
    match hdk::commit_entry(&metric_entry) {
        Ok(metric_address) => {
            match hdk::link_entries(
                           &user_address,
                           &metric_address,
                           "metric_by_user"
                       ) {
                           Ok(link_address) => metric_address.into(),
                           Err(e) => e.into(),
                       }
                   }
                   Err(hdk_error) => hdk_error.into(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For error 1, just check this example, and copy it: 
https://developer.holochain.org/api/0.0.2/hdk/api/fn.commit_entry.html

For error 2, just do

```
link_result.into()
```

which converts it into a JsonString

For error 3, use

```
.addresses()
```

instead of .links, this can be seen here: https://developer.holochain.org/api/0.0.2/holochain_wasm_utils/api_serialization/get_links/struct.GetLinksResult.html

And for error 4 just do

```
hdk_error.into()
```

and remove it from the json! wrapping that it looks like you're attempting :)

In general, if you see a reference to something relating to the hdk, use the search feature of the API ref to find out more about it, its very good

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from 0.0.1 to 0.0.2 was exactly what I did recently for the todo-list example. I just created a branch for the old version so you can compare the two

- https://github.com/willemolding/holochain-rust-todo
- https://github.com/willemolding/holochain-rust-todo/tree/working-on-v0.0.1

From memory some of the gotchas are:

- commit_entry now takes a single reference to an Entry object
- Links must be included as part of the define_zome! or they cannot be created
- move from serde_json Value to JsonString
- Need to include `holochain_core_types_derive = { git = "https://github.com/holochain/holochain-rust" , tag = "holochain-cmd-v0.0.2" }` in the cargo.toml
- Responses from get_entry are generic entry types and can be converted into a local type, say ListEntry, as `ListEntry::try_from(entry.value())`

There are a whole lot more so its probably best to check out the repo.